# How to use a Flutter page in a custom Android Activity or Fragment?

Tags: android, xml, flutter, kotlin, flutter-method-channel

I am working on a project where an old library is being used in Android natively. Because of this, I am forced to work in Kotlin and use a xml file in order to view some elements on the screen. However, I am questioning myself if there is a way to create a custom activity/fragment in Android and call a flutter screen file where I can use all the Flutter widgets within the app. I am currently using method channels in order to communicate between Kotlin and Dart and this is why I came up with this question. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to launch an Android Activity in which Flutter engine will be able to display UI and perform any actions you want within a native Android application.

To do so, you need to create a Flutter module, here is the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup).